# How many comparisons do I need to rank using Bradley-Terry?

Tags: bradley-terry-model

I have recently learned about a method for ranking items based on comparisons called the Bradley-Terry method. I am using it to rank about 500 items.

I am wondering how many comparisons do I need to make if I uniformly pick items to compare each time. What are some mathematical models I can use to find this out? How can I assign say a confidence level to my ranking? Or have enough comparisons to guarantee a certain confidence level?

Comment: Isn't it more like "the certainty increases the more comparisons you do"?  And doesn't the certainty vary depending on the actual votes?

Comment: Can you give more details? And how precise do you need it to be? To answer your question we would need to know about that!